# Unable to drag Mobile and Lightning Action button into Cusom Buttons in Page Layou

Tags: visual-workflow, page-layout, trailhead

I am attempting this [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/flow_calculate/flow_calculate_implement).

I am unable to verify the step because I cannot follow the instruction:

8c Under Opportunity Detail, click and drag **Calculate Discount** onto Custom Buttons.

How can I get past this?

Custom Buttons is not a valid drop target, so I cannot complete the trailhead.[image: Page Layout]

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's just an error in the steps within the trailhead. You should be dragging it to the `Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions` as you're working/verifying it in the *Lightning* UI.

You'll first need to click the `override the predefined actions` (in blue). Then, you can drag your action to it.

[image]

You can click on the bottom right (Question, feedback or help) to get assistance as well as that should be updated. I used that mechanism to create a case to update this in particular.

---

If you really did need to add it where they identified, you'd need to go to the `Buttons` in the top window and select your created button from there.

[image]

Comment: Tried that. Trailhead fails to verify that it's been done. Not big problem, just annoying, and makes getting to the next stage a but more of a faff.

Comment: does it say anything as to why it failed verification?

Comment: Because the 'Calculate Discount' button was not added to the correct place in the page layout. But I can't add it where it wants to go!

Comment: well if that's the issue I had added an update on how to add it in the classic custom button location. I'm not sure if you should remove what is in the lightning actions area or not.